# Receiving large data over tcp - is socket.MSG_WAITALL directly into numpy buffer a bad idea?

Tags: arrays, numpy, sockets, tcp, buffer

Summary: I am receiving big image data over a tcp connection. What is the best way to put it into an numpy array without using too much space and copying?

I am getting image data from a hyperspectral camera (having way more than 3 wavelength bands) over tcp. The camera is kind of a blackbox to me. I want to receive the data and have it in a numpy array without too much data copying. I started with the examples around (on the socket module and stackoverflow). But I was not sure if it's the best way so I wanted to use a numpy array as a buffer. But therefor I had to use socket.MSG_WAITALL which I found on GitHub. (because approach 3 - see below - was not working) But it is rarely used and in no example and I learned about TCP sending in unpredictable chunks. So I wanted to know what is behind that, why it should not be used(or should it?) and in general what do you think is the best way to achieve this.

So here are my 3 tries (1 and 2 both run fine and in nearly same time):

```
import socket
import numpy as np
def receiveImage1(self):
    #typical example - should have best performance they said
    MSGLEN = 480 * 252 * 640

    chunks = []
    bytes_recd = 0
    while bytes_recd < MSGLEN:
        chunk = self.connection.recv(min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, 2048))
        bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)
        chunks.append(chunk)

    #is this a copy?
    b = b''.join(chunks)
    n = np.frombuffer(b, np.dtype('<H')).reshape((480,252,320))
    return n

def receiveImage2(self):
    #create buffer and write into it
    MSGLEN = 480 * 252 * 640
    npbuffer = np.ones((480, 252, 320), np.dtype('<H'))

    self.connection.recv_into(npbuffer, MSGLEN, socket.MSG_WAITALL)

    return npbuffer

def receiveImage3(self):
    #create buffer and write into it in chunks (not working)
    MSGLEN = 480 * 252 * 640
    npbuffer = np.ones((480, 252, 320), np.dtype('<H'))

    bytes_recd = 0
    while bytes_recd < MSGLEN:
        lgt = self.connection.recv_into(npbuffer,min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, 2048))
        bytes_recd = bytes_recd + lgt
    return npbuffer
```

So 1 and 2 run nearly the same time. I am wondering about advantages and disadvantages and about copies and space used. What would you prefer?

When trying 3 I thought the pointer to the buffer will go with the writing, so it will fill the complete buffer. (Of course it does not, instead it does overwrite the first bytes over and over) So I was trying to find a way to give the buffer some offset or something, but I could not find it.(I was hoping for some behaviour like a C-Pointer) Is there some clever way to do this?

So in general what is the best approach to do this?

Thank you very much for your answers!